# Cryptic Babel error in React web app when using Stellar SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, blockchain

Im developing a web app using React JS(Using Create React App) which will run on Stellar and Im using the official JS Stellar SDK. However, after integrating the Stellar SDK, I get a Babel error due to the Stellar SDK. Has anyone faced this issue before? The error is as follows :

```
    ./node_modules/js-xdr/lib/opaque.js
    Module not found: Can't resolve 'babel-runtime/helpers/interop-
    require' in user//node_modules/js-xdr/lib'
```

I have tried removing and installing the node modules but the error still persists.

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
 "name": "myProject",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "axios": "^0.17.1",
 "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
 "font-awesome-animation": "^0.1.0",
 "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
 "moment": "^2.20.1",
 "node-sass-chokidar": "^0.0.3",
 "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
 "react": "^16.2.0",
 "react-atv-img": "^0.1.1",
 "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
 "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.0.0",
 "react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.10.0",
 "react-parallax": "^1.5.1",
 "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
 "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
 "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
 "recharts": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
 "redux": "^3.7.2",
 "stellar-sdk": "^0.8.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
"start-js": "react-scripts start",
"start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
"build-js": "react-scripts build",
"build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
}
```

Edit: Added the package.json

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` ?

Comment: I have added the package.json in the question

Comment: Try `npm i babel-plugin-transform-runtime`